# UIButton showing multiple times on UITableView when created dynamically in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uibutton, ios5.1

After trying various options, and reading numerous answers on SO, I am posting this question hoping somebody can provide some insight or a solution to this problem:

iOS5.1, XCode 4.4.1, Storyboard, ARC

I have a "Grouped" tableview, with each cell containing bunch of labels, images and buttons. One of the label, **Description** label, for it the text can be large or small, which means if text is large I have to increase the size of the label accordingly and place the buttons below accordingly as well. I am able to do all this, but the problem is that buttons appears twice when I scroll past the first cell and keeps repeating as I scroll.

Here's the code, all I am doing is calculating the height of label based on text, resizing the label, and then placing the 3 buttons below the description label accordingly.

The code below is just for one button but this should give the idea of what i am doing. I have tried to do similar stuff in "willDisplayCell", in the custom cell class but still the 3 buttons keeps repeating when i scroll down in the tableview. PLease refer the screenshot, the first three buttons shouldn't even show.

I noticed that position of first 3 buttons is same as if it ignores the **sizeIncrement**, meaning "359.0f + sizeIncrement +20" minus the "sizeIncrement", "sizeIncrement"= the height of description label after calculation

I also noticed that if i do

```
float y = 359.0f + 20;
```

instead of this

```
float y = 359.0f + sizeIncrement +20;
```

the repetition of Buttons problem is gone.

P.S: I know this is not the best code, but I have been trying lot of stuff to solve the problem so not bothered with best practices etc at this point.

[image: 2 Cells displayed on screenshot, first 3 buttons shouldNOT show]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tipsid";

 TipsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil)
 {
     cell = [[TipsCell alloc]
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
             reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 }

 id tip = [_tips objectAtIndex: [indexPath section]];

 NSDictionary *tipForIndex = [_tips objectAtIndex: [indexPath section]];
 float sizeIncrement = [Utility getLabelHeightForText:[tipForIndex objectForKey:@"tipDescripion"]
                                            withWidth:285.0f
                                             withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]];

 // Here I Resize the Label, code below to create a button and position accordingly.

 float y = 359.0f + sizeIncrement +20;

 UIButton *likeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, y, 80, 26)];
 likeButton.tag = [indexPath section];     

 // add targets and actions
 [likeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(likebuttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [likeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"likebutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 [likeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"likedButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

 // add to a view
 [cell.contentView addSubview:likeButton];
```

.....similarly create 2 other buttons

Answer (score 1):

You should move button creating into `if (cell == nil)` operator:

```
if (cell == nil)
{
   cell = [[TipsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   // like button
   float y = 359.0f + sizeIncrement +20;

   UIButton *likeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, y, 80, 26)];
   likeButton.tag = LIKE_BUTTON_TAG_UNIQUE_IN_CONTENT_VIEW; // <<<<<<<<<<----------------     

   // add targets and actions
   [likeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(likebuttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [likeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"likebutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   [likeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"likedButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

   // add to a view
   [cell.contentView addSubview:likeButton];

   // other buttons
}

// and here you can adjust button positions
UIButton *likeButton = [self.contentView viewWithIndex:LIKE_BUTTON_TAG_UNIQUE_IN_CONTENT_VIEW];
```

Comment: Nekto, thanks for the answer. I don't have my Development Machine with me right now, so haven't tried your suggestions yet, I have a question though, normally cell==nil returns false because following code reuses an already instantiated cell "[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];", so how will moving the code inside if condition help?

Comment: Why do you need to create new buttons if you are reusing cells that have already those buttons?

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understand your question but in design mode (Storyboard) there are no buttons in cell, I need to dynamically create buttons and add them below description label in cell, as shown in the code. I tried your suggestion but like I mentioned it never goes inside if condition so the buttons are never created.